# $1-\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)s^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, generating-functions

I´m trying to prove that $$ f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1-\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)s^2}&   if & 0 \leq s  < 1\\
             \\ 1 &  if& s=1 
             \end{array}
   \right.  $$ is a generating  function of a distribution with $p \in [0,1] $.

I´m trying to use the binomial theorem but I can´t solve it. Someone could help me to prove that this is a generating  function of a distribution pls.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Get the Maclaurin series for $1-\sqrt{1-x}$, replace $x$ with $ax^2$, and then sum the coefficients, set the result equal to $1$, and solve for $a$. Then hope all the coefficients are $\geq 0$.

Comment: Ok I got $$1-\sqrt{1-x} = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16~\ldots}$$ replazing $x=ax^2$, we have $$1-\sqrt{1-ax^2} = \frac{ax^2}{2}+\frac{a^2x^4}{8}+\frac{a^3x^6}{16}+\ldots$$ and if $$1 = 1-\sqrt{1-ax^2} = \frac{ax^2}{2}+\frac{a^2x^4}{8}+\frac{a^3x^6}{16}+\ldots$$ then $$0 = \sqrt{1-ax^2} = 1 - \frac{ax^2}{2}-\frac{a^2x^4}{8}-\frac{a^3x^6}{16 }-\ldots$$ Is it correct? But How can I solve for $a$ if I got the complete serie ?

Comment: You want to sum the coefficients, not the series itself. That is, presumably $1-\sqrt{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n x^n$, and you want to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n$. One would hope that this is $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x)$...

Comment: Ok, so  $$1-\sqrt{1-x} = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}+ \ldots = $$ $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{(1+n)}{\frac{1}{2} \choose{n}  } x^n$$ for $n>0$ ?

Comment: sorry Is it $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{2} \choose{n}  } x^n$$ for $n>0$ ?

Comment: Can you give me some hint of how find the distribution of this generating function of distribution?

Comment: Well I understand that I need to calculate $P(X=x)$ with the r.a. given but how can I associate to the generating function of distribution ?